# running multiple commands in php through system()

Tags: php, batch-file, cmd

I'm successfully able to execute with this following command:

```
system('C:/Program Files/PSPP/bin/psppire.exe ');
```

i want to do something like opening a file through this exe e.g.

```
system('C:/Program Files/PSPP/bin/psppire.exe, C:/xampp/htdocs/csv/txtfiles/PSPPfile.txt');
```

This above command should open txt file in psppire.exe!
Help me out! Thanks.

Comment: Try leaving out the comma `,`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Windows OS(according to your example) - separate path for executable file and path for target file with space.
The working example is shown below:

```
system('"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "C:\arsetup.log"');
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a comma in the name of the command you're using. That's a problem in and of itself. I don't think the name of that executable is "pspire.exe,".

Also you may want to quote the different paths because they contain spaces. So it maybe should become

```
system('"C:\Program Files\PSPP\bin\psppire.exe" "C:\xampp\htdocs\csv\txtfiles\PSPPfile.txt"');
```

Also you should note that I used backslashes, which is the correct directory separator for Windows. To make this universal you can use the constant DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR